# Why does absolute navigation URL not clear navigation stack?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

While I was investigating on an issue that makes my app staying on splash screen even after navigating to another page, I found out something that seems weird to me.

I managed to reproduce the issue in a small and simple project.
Basically I have 3 pages and ViewModels in my Prism project: SplashPage (ContentPage), MainPage (ContentPage), RootPage (MasterDetailPage).

They are all registered for navigation, as well as the NavigationPage.

Here is what I have in my App.xaml.cs:

```cs
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/SplashPage");
}
```

And in the SplashPageViewModel's OnNavigatedTo override:

```cs
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"URI: {NavigationService.GetNavigationUriPath()}");
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/RootPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");
    Debug.WriteLine($"URI: {NavigationService.GetNavigationUriPath()}");     
}
```

And here is the output:

```
[0:] URI: /SplashPage
[0:] URI: /RootPage/NavigationPage/MainPage/SplashPage?useModalNavigation=true
```

I feel very confused because I was thinking that any navigation request that begins with "/" should clear the navigation stack. So why does the SplashPage remain ?

Comment: try this : `await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("app:///RootPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");`

Comment: Thanks but same result

Answer (score 2):

You've got an interesting problem!!. I've never tried navigating in `OnNavigatedTo`

You might want to talk to Brian Lagunas about the internal workings of `OnNavigatedTo` or may be take a look at the [repo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)

After reading you're question, I was able to reproduce the same behavior. Taking it a step further I've added some delay in calling the `MainPage` and it worked just fine.

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"URI: {NavigationService.GetNavigationUriPath()}");
    Task.Run(async() => {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/RootPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }});
    Debug.WriteLine($"URI: {NavigationService.GetNavigationUriPath()}");     
}
```

The output in console is still the same, but when i print the Navigation page in `MainPage` `OnNavigatedTo` it is showing correctly! and the UI/Navigation stack doesn't have the `SplashPage`

**Beware:** Its a hack and I strongly suggest against calling `Task.Run` unnecessarily

Comment: Yeah I hoped Brian could read this post.
I haven't checked the navigation stack itself because I assumed what is returned from GetNavigationUriPath reflects precisely what we can found in stack. But it seems this is not true.

Comment: Yea, i guess it cleans ups in the background after pushing the page... so if you navigate "quick enough" you may run in to issues

Comment: Sorry, but when you say "I was able to reproduce the same behaviour", are you saying that the splash page stays above the main page ? Because even if in my real app I actually had this issue, I wasn't able to reproduce it in the sample app I built prior to posting: the MainPage is showed. But the Navigation Uri seems wrong.

Comment: Naah just the NavigationUri... the stack is just fine

Comment: "Beware: Its a hack and I strongly suggest against calling Task.Run unnecessarily" ...how come you recommend against calling Task.Run unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

For Clearing Navigation Stack

Use Abosulute Uri like below to clear all navigation stack

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("app:///RootPage/NavigationPage/MainPage", UriKind.Absolute));
```

In your case seems you only want splashscreen page to be removed from the stack then you can simply change like below.

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("../RootPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

Note:- The above syntax will clear SplashScreen from the NavigationStack (Also, this will work if you are using prism.forms 7+ version)

Comment: The first solution works, thank you. The second one does not work because relative navigation is only allowed inside NavigationPage.
But that does not says why the syntax in my first example does not  work.